# Encrypt text in file with ruby and cipher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption

I need to make an encryptor and decryptor which reads a file with text and encrypts it and then generates a txt file with the encryption.
Then you must decrypt that same txt file
So far I managed to encrypt the text and put it in the file but I still can not decrypt the text that is inside this.
The encrypt work without the files

```
**The problem starts here**

#Decrypt
data = ''
File.open('text2.txt','r') do |archivo|
    while line = archivo.gets
       data += line
    end
end


encrypted = data

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc")
cipher.decrypt
cipher.key = key
cipher.iv = iv

# and decrypt it
decrypted = cipher.update(encrypted)
decrypted << cipher.final
puts "decrypted: #{decrypted}\n"
```

The error is : encrypt.rb:48:in `final': wrong final block length (OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError)
        from encrypt.rb:48:in`'

Comment: Where is the test key, IV, data, encrypted data prior to writing, after reading, after decryption? Encrypted should be provided in hex. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Separate and simplify the problem. First get the encryption working in the code with a test string to an encrypted string to a decrypted string. When that works add the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the block where you write out the encryption to the file `text2.txt`. You're using `archivo.puts`, but you want to use `archivo.write`. `puts` will append a newline character at the end of each line, so you're writing `encrypted + "\n"` to the file. When you try to decrypt it, that extra newline character messes it up. If you use `write`, it just writes exactly what you give it without the extra character.

What you want to do instead:

```
File.open('text2.txt', 'w') do |archivo|
  archivo.write encrypted
end
```

Or even better yet:

```
File.write('text2.txt', encrypted)
```